# Chrome Canary Sass debugging switches between scss files and compiled css

Tags: google-chrome, sass, google-chrome-devtools

After setting up source maps for my scss files, and getting sass debugging up and running for canary, I'm hitting a small but frustrating snag. When I first load or reload the page and inspect an element, I get a reference to the .scss file in the Matched CSS Rules window. [screenshot 1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1Irq.png)

When I go to switch up the styles, for instance changing the background color, as soon as I'm done making the change, the file path instantly changes to the compiled css file. [screenshot 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imT6z.png) Any ideas for why this might be happening?

Comment: This sounds like a bug report (especially since source maps are still in testing), not an SO question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, when you modify the CSS, the source mapping between CSS and SCSS is broken, since it is no longer correct. To restore it, you should save the updated SCSS onto disk in the DevTools Sources panel (with sass running in the watch mode) and have DevTools reload your CSS. Then your source mapping will be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's still not working correctly for me though, unless I missed something. The mapping seems to be alright... If I make changes in the dev tools sources panel to a scss file, I see the changes in my text editor, the sass gets compiled, and when I reload the page the changes are there. But, I still get the same original problem I described above.

Comment: Correct. Any changes to the CSS resource will invalidate the mapping. This is something to be solved on our side.